# Why toast table doesn't affect expain (analyze)?

Tags: postgresql

Here is table structure

```
create table test as 
select 
   lpad('x',100,'x') as a1, 
   (SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT chr((65 + round(random() * 25)):: int) FROM generate_series(1,1024*1024)), '')) as a2 
from generate_series(1,5*1024);
```

Total size of table 770Kb plus toast table 5.8Gb

Let's run

```
explain (analyze, buffers, timing) select a2 from test

"Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..145.20 rows=5120 width=18) (actual  time=0.041..2.959 rows=5120 loops=1)"
"Buffers: shared hit=2 read=92"
"Planning time: 1.771 ms"
"Execution time: 3.375 ms"
```

Which means toast table is not scanned. That's why result of explain doesn't match to real query.

I guess, this is an planner optimization issue. No consumer of data, no need to read them. But result of explain, suppose match(at least on timings approximately) to real query.

Are keywords **explain, analyze, buffers** part of syntax and they are  inserted into AST built by postgres query parser?  Or they are cut from query and postgres execute rest of query, but keeps in "mind" to get statistical details of execution?

If someone can confirm or explain why it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot know why it was chosen to do it like that, but I guess it is a side effect of PostgreSQL's attempt to defer detoasting of a value as long as possible.

You could force PostgreSQL to detoast it as part of the query execution, that way you'll get more realistic data:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING) SELECT length(a2) FROM test;
```

Comment: Detoast is possible but change output results. This query is primitive, that is why difference easily noticeable. But what is query complicated and data spreading not constant in table.

Comment: I'd say that the problem only occurs for the columns in the `SELECT` list of the query. All intermediary values that are used in the query will have to be detoasted anyway. So just attach a `length()` to every varlena column in the `SELECT` list.